# I (European citizen) lost my job in Denmark. How long can I stay while looking for a new job?

Tags: denmark

I've been working 2 years for a company, then lost my job. How long can I stay here while looking for a new one?

It should be straightforward to Google for it, but spent some time and I can't find a definite answer.

Comment: The general principles are [described here](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/residence-rights/jobseekers/index_en.htm) Typically you are in a more favourable situation than someone who just came to Denmark to look for a job and should be able to stay as long as you are getting unemployment benefits and qualify as a jobseeker under local rules. You can also stay if you have enough income/savings, even without a job. Unfortunately, I don't know the details of the unemployment benefit system in Denmark and I am not sure how these principles are implemented there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website mentions that you may stay up to 6 months or more if you can prove that you are seeking employment.

https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/You-want-to-apply/Residence-as-a-Nordic-citizen-or-EU-or-EEA-citizen/Union-citizens-and-EEA-nationals

You will also need to apply for a residence certificate if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I believe these rules apply to people who just arrived and never worked in Denmark. Rules for people who lost their job after working in Denmark for some time may be more favourable (but I don't really know the details, just that this makes a difference under EU law).